# Laravel 4.2 Eloquent Check ID

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i got 2 tables

"hostgame" -> where games are hosted
"games" -> where every game hosted are getting all their respective info's here

We'll i got "game_id" inside "hostgame" table, as of now, all the games are posted in the website, i would like to filter those games based by "game_id" in the "hostgame" table, and only show the game that has been hosted.

How should i do it?

GameController.php

```
    public function select()
{
    // TODO: Pls revise this. This is not the right way to do
    $weekly_dates = $this->get_days( Config::get('game.year'), 9  );

    $this->params['weekly_dates'] = $weekly_dates;
    $this->params['weekly_games'] = array();

    foreach($weekly_dates as $date ) {

        $from = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($date));
        $to = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime($date));

        //foreach($hostgames as $hostgame){
        $this->params['hostgame'] = Hostgame::all();
        dd($this->params['hostgame']);
        $this->params['weekly_games'][$date] = Game::whereRaw('schedule >= ? and schedule <= ?', array($from, $to) )->get();
        //}

        //$this->params['weekly_games'][$date] = Game::has()('schedule >= ? and schedule <= ?', array($from, $to) )->hostgames();
        //$this->params['weekly_games'][$date] = Hostgame::whereHas('game', function($q) {
            //$q->whereRaw('schedule >= ? and schedule <= ?', array('34365', '2435') )->get();
        //});

    }
```

select.blade.php

```
          <?php $day = 0 ?>
      @foreach ($weekly_games as $date => $games )
      @if($games)
      <div id="slide-content-{{ $day }}">
        <h2>Sunday Games {{ $date }}</h2>
          @foreach ($games as $game )

          <p><a href="{{ URL::to('game/draft/'.$game->id) }}"> {{ $game->home_name }} Vs {{ $game->away_name }}</a></p>
          @endforeach
        @endif
      </div>
      <?php $day++ ?>
      @endforeach
```

Thank you, for now all the games are showing, by their own respective dates.
I want to show only the games that has been hosted.

Comment: Do you use the eloquent model? -> http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent

Comment: yes i did.. but i'm asking if someone knew about what i have to do with this, im desperate enough to go with a query. but if it can be able to do it with eloquent then that's why im asking.

Comment: okay, if I understand it correctly - you have two tables, one for games that are being hosted and one for the games itself, correct? So, each host belongs to one game?

Comment: yes, respectively it does belong to their own games, so the thing is the "hostgame" table is where the game being created, and the "games" table is where the information is being fetched, so specifically, im trying to find the "hostgame.game_id" -> "game.id", if the id is the same, then it's going to pull the "schedule" data, and the "home_team" and "away_team" and show the game info in the front end

Comment: Okay, I get it. So please add your model of Game.php and Hostgame.php to a gist (https://gist.github.com) or in your post and I will help you to have the correct relation

Comment: Here's the game.php and hostgame.php http://pastebin.com/3hc0a76J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve your goal. Since you already have your game id in the hosts list, try this:

1. Add a function for a single game to the GameController.php `public function getSingleGame($id) { // logic here }`
2. Next, add the following (Controller) route to your routes.php to have link between the Route, your Controller and the template: `Route::get('game/draft/{id}', ['as' => 'show_single_game', 'uses' => 'GameController@getSingleGame']);` You are now able to access the route by a specific name (show_single_game).
3. Now you could write your URL route like this: `{{ link_to_route('show_single_game', $game->home_name . " Vs " . $game->away_name, array($game->id) ) }}` Laravel will create the link for you, so don't worry about the URL, this is now set by the route.

The logic for the GameController getSingleGame:

```
public function getSingleGame($id) {
    // find the game by id
    $game = Game::findOrFail($id); 

    // assuming your template is located in views/games/show.blade.php
    return View::make('games/show')
        ->with('game', $game);
}
```

I would suggest to read this book for laravel 4.X -> http://daylerees.com/codebright/controllers and for version 5 watch this awesome series: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining as clear as possible.. thank you so much

Comment: I have not tested this, but it should work (hope so ;)), so just ask and I will edit the post!